# Curl does not send a post request in argo workflow

Tags: curl, containers, argo-workflows, argo

I am trying to send a post request using curl in argo workflow.

After I run the application. It shows success but the curl does not send a post request.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: webhook-
spec:
  serviceAccountName: workflow-pods-sa
  entrypoint: curl-a-website
  podGC:
    strategy: OnPodSuccess
  deleteDelayDuration: 10s
  templates:
    - name: curl-a-website
      container:
        image: curlimages/curl:latest
        command:
          - sh
        source: |
          echo (curl -d '{"bucketName":"Dont call me Shirley"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://webhook.site/7300aabe-d28b-44a8-91c5-5664015bc99a)
```